# oneM2M - Difference between ASN-CSE and MN-CSE?

Tags: onem2m

I can not understand (in practice) which is the difference between ASN-CSE and MN-CSE.
For instance in the fig 1 of this article (https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/19/20/4567?type=check_update&version=1), both include CSE, both have a side connection to NSE and both are connected to IN-CSE.

Thank you

I have read about the architecture and in articles usually ASN-CSE is not used...

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the ASN-CSE and the MN-CSE is mostly architectural. Generally speaking you can view the ASN-CSE as CSE built for a specific purpose whereas the MN-CSE is general purpose, as you might find in a gateway.

An example of an ASN-CSE that we are in the process of defining is for cellular IoT devices. The CSE will use the existing oneM2M features (CSFs), but it will not have all of the features and capabilities of oneM2M. That particular ASN-CSE will have features that help make sure IoT communication using cellular channels are bandwidth and power efficient and work well within the core network.

The paper that you referenced (I know some of the authors) is focused on a basic ASN-CSE, which supports functions that are not supported by an ASN-AE, but still be hosted on MCU sized processors. For instance, if you have an AE on an mcu, you cannot directly address a resource or feature managed by the AE (you can using subscriptions via the MN-CSE). However for an ASN-CSE when you target the resource in the CSE (ASN-CSE) you are already on the device.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: So, a MN-CSE "must" be CSE complete while a ASN-CSE may not be full CSE.

Comment: There are a couple of service functions that are essential even for a small CSE on an ASN, like data and connectivity management. But otherwise a deployment is free to decide what service functions to provide. This is in general indicated by the "supportedResourceTypes" attribute of the CSEBase resource. Even an MN-CSE doesn't need to be "complete". There are actually service functions that can only be hosted on an IN-CSE (like subscriber profile and other network management related functions).